# Django reverse foreign key leading to duplicate queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to use ViewSet to return list of all assets with the asset type name (instead of just id) but according to [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), my queries are being duplicated leading to slower results.

1 Asset type can have multiple assets.

So, when I try to retrieve all assets (children) -- it's trying to fetch the asset type (parent) names for each of the assets (children) but it's running one query for every asset (child). Looks something like this: It's duplicated 6 times because I have 6 values in the Asset table currently.

```
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (27,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.99    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (27,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.99    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (27,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.00    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (29,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.95    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (29,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.99    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (29,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.
```

**Expected Output**

All I want is just a list of all the Assets along with the AssetType names -- is there a better way to do this?

Here are my models:

```
class AssetType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "mm_asset_type"

class Asset(models.Model):
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "mm_asset_registry"
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class AssetTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AssetType
        fields = "__all__"


class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_type_name = serializers.CharField(source='asset_type.name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ("id", "asset_type_name", "asset_name", "display_name")
```

Finally, this is my ViewSet

```
class AssetViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Asset.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer
```

So, when I try to retrieve all assets -- it's trying to fetch the asset type names for each of the assets but it's running one query for every asset. Looks something like this:

```
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (27,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.99    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (27,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.99    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (27,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.00    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (29,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.95    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (29,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.        3.99    
Sel Expl
+   
QUERY = 'SELECT TOP 21 [mm_asset_type].[id], [mm_asset_type].[name], [mm_asset_type].[description] FROM [mm_asset_type] WHERE [mm_asset_type].[id] = %s' - PARAMS = (29,)
 6 similar queries.  Duplicated 3 times.
```

**Expected Output**

All I want is just a list of all the Assets (children) along with the AssetType (parent) names -- is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch the types with the same query:

```
class AssetViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Asset.objects.select_related('asset_type')
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer
```

This will thus also fetch the `asset_type` fields in the same query as the one to fetch the `Asset`s, and thus reduces the total number of queries to one.